# DllImport - C types to .NET types

Tags: c#, f#, dllimport

I've got dll function

```
DLLExport int PatchSomething(char*, char*, DWORD, unsigned char*, unsigned short int);
```

but can't fully transfer parameters to .NET

F# :

module RNInvoke

```
open System
open System.Runtime.InteropServices
open Microsoft.FSharp.NativeInterop
open Microsoft.FSharp.Math

module Native =
    [<System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("DesuDLL.dll",EntryPoint="add")>]
    extern int PatchSomething(char*, char*, DWORD, unsigned char*, unsigned short int);
```

or C#

```
[DllImport("DesuDLL.dll")]
private static extern int PatchSomething(char*, char*, DWORD, unsigned char*, unsigned short int);
```

errors on **unsigned char*** and **unsigned short int**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like:

```
[DllImport("DesuDLL.dll")]
private static extern int PatchSomething(string a,string b,uint c,string d,ushort e);
```

You might need to throw CharSet = Auto into the attribute too. My only concerns are on the unsigned char pointer.